# I have to create a function that returns True or False if a list is sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a function called `isSorted()` and test if a list is sorted or not in Python 3.7. Said function has to return either `True` or `False` for whatever case may occur.

This is my code

```
def isSorted(newList):
    for x in newList:
        if newList[0] <= x:
            return True
        else:
            return False 

def main ():
    newList = [1, 2, 3]
    print(isSorted(newList))
    newList = [1]
    print(isSorted(newList))
    newList = list(range(10))
    print(isSorted(newList))
    newList[9] = 3
    print(isSorted(newList))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I specifically need the `newList[9] = 3` line to return `False`, but it keeps returning `True`. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: What do you think `newList[9] = 3` does? This isn't a comparison, it's an assignment.

Comment: I think you're not handling the case for newList[9], your if statement in the for loop is checking the first element i.e accessing the first index newList[0], also pls add your full traceback for the exact error you're seeing :)

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @FishingCode The OP didn't say that they are getting an error message.

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you're asking, and the `isSorted()` function does not behave as the name implies.

Comment: @AMC That's the question.

Comment: @Selcuk Oh, I thought the question was specifically about the result of `isSorted(newList)` after `newList[9] = 3`.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

(1) You should compare each element with the previous one, not with the first element.

(2) You immediately return `True` if the first check succeeds in the loop. Your code doesn't even process the 9th element.

A fixed implementation could be:

```
def isSorted(newList):
    for i in range(len(newList) - 1):
        if newList[i] > newList[i + 1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Your test then should print:

```
True
True
True
False
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been stuck on it for a while. I am new to python, thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it if it helped.